# Collectors.groupingBy for Map<Long, List<String>> with some string manipulation

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have the following `List<String>`, `resultList` that I want to convert to a `Map<Long, List<String>>`

```
["7802,Campaign submitted - audience list", "7802,Test Static Coupon", "7802,submit order", "7802,order creation failed", "7802,submit order", "8153,existing order test - resubmitting", "8153,existing order test - reorder", "8153,test", "8153,test", "8953,audience newly duplicated list"]
```

The `Map` should look like the following:

```
{
   7802: [Campaign submitted - audience list, Test Static Coupon, submit order, order creation failed, submit order],
   8153: [existing order test - resubmitting, existing order test - reorder, test, test],
   8953: [audience newly duplicated list]
}
```

I have the following code so far but I can't figure out how to manipulate the strings to save to the list in the `Map`:

```
resultList.stream().collect(
      Collectors.groupingBy(s -> Long.parseLong(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(','))), 
      HashMap::new, 
      Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

The code above returns the following:

```
{
   7802: [7802,Campaign submitted - audience list, 7802,Test Static Coupon, 7802,submit order, 7802,order creation failed, 7802,submit order],
   8153: [8153,existing order test - resubmitting, 8153,existing order test - reorder, 8153,test, 8153,test],
   8953: [8953,audience newly duplicated list]
}
```

How can I manipulate the strings to get the required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more convenient to work with if you `split` up the two parts of the string *first*, using `map`. With a `Stream<String[]>`, you can group by `x[0]`, and map the groups to `x[1]` using a downstream collector.

```
var result = list.stream()
    .map(x -> x.split(",", 2))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> Long.parseLong(x[0]),
        Collectors.mapping(x -> x[1], Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

If you specifically want `HashMap`s and `ArrayList`s instead:

```
var result = list.stream()
    .map(x -> x.split(",", 2))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> Long.parseLong(x[0]),
        HashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(x -> x[1], Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a downstream mapper to apply an additional mapping to the values of the map.

I'd start by splitting each string and then working on the relevant split array's element:

```java
Map<Long, List<String>> resultMap =
    resultList.stream()
              .map(s -> s.split(","))
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                  s -> Long.parseLong(s[0]),
                  Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1], Collectors.toList())));
```